# Display image on search results for chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I've just published my first chrome extension to the webstore. However I see that the image shown next to the extension in the search results is just a small low quality version of the 128x128 icon that I uploaded when publishing. Notice how the second extension has a nice high quality image shown:

[image: search results screenshot]

Here is a list of images that I can supply:

- [Manifest icons](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#icons) sizes: 16x16, 48x48, 128x128
- [Extension icon](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/images?hl=en#icons) size 128x128
- [Promotional images](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/images?hl=en#promo) sizes: 440x280, 920x680, 1400x560
- [Screenshots](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/images?hl=en#screenshots) sizes: 1280x800 or 640x400

Of these, which is the one that displays in the search results shown in the screenshot above?

I should add, that I published the extension only 2 days ago and while I only uploaded the smallest promotional image, it appears that it has been reviewed and approved as there is no message saying Pending or Rejected on the extension's settings:

[image: promotional images screenshot]

Answer (score 23):

The image in the search results is a shrunk version of the 440x280 promo image.

Since your search result is still showing your icon, padded, I think that your images have *not* been approved *yet*. Contrary to what [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/images#promo) says, you won't be able to see the review status of your image.

It can take anywhere between a few days and a couple of weeks before the promo image is approved.

Comment: It has nothing to do with pending status or not. Even my webapp has this tiny image instead of a proper tile sized image. don't know why.

Comment: any update?
I uploaded an extension 2 days ago and still the small icon is shown

Comment: Looks like this estimate is still accurate. I published some tiles on Saturday and they were approved Tuesday morning.